# What hardware is needed to support Miracast?

Tags: mirroring, windows-8.1-preview

With Windows 8.1 natively supporting Miracast, we saw a demonstration of screen mirroring via Xbox One at the ongoing //build/ conference. If I want to mirror my laptop screen running Windows 8.1, what extra hardware would I need both on receiving end and transmitting end to support Miracast?

Comment: Would people who are downvoting/closing this question also please explain why they are doing so.

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/607146/intel-widi-miracast-receiver-hardware-software-for-diy-htpc

Answer (score 16):

Transmitting end:

- WiFi device with NDIS 6.3 driver.  (Check with `Get-NetAdapter |
  Select Name, NdisVersion` in PowerShell.)
- Video driver that supports    WDDM 1.3 (new for Windows 8.1).

Receiving end:
Any device certified for Miracast?
Netgear Push2TV confirmed to work.

Comment: You can in powershell write:
"Get-NetAdapter | Select Name, NdisVersion"
to get the NDIS version of your WiFi card... And you can run:
"DxDiag.exe"
to find out what WDDM version your graphics driver is...

Comment: Per @zmurf I checked and my graphics card driver model is WDDM 1.3 and my Wifi NDIS version is 6.3. This tuturial (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/matt-harrington/archive/2014/05/02/how-to-project-from-a-computer-to-a-tv.aspx) suggests I cannot mirror. Is there something else I need?

Comment: Same here. WDDM 1.3 and NDIS 6.3. I don't have the option to add a wireless monitor.

Comment: Turns out that not all WDDM 1.3 drivers support Miracast.  Upgrade to the latest driver available at the manufacturer's web site and see if that helps.  NVIDIA did not add support until around a year after Windows 8.1 was released.

Comment: Link appears to be dead

Comment: "Within Windows" blog appears to have been abandoned/removed.  An old version of the page is available at archive.org.  https://web.archive.org/web/20131208153812/http://withinwindows.com/within-windows/2013/6/30/windows-81-features-miracast-wireless-display-tech-and-it-works-well

Comment: Intel WiDi Applications Have Been Discontinued https://www.intel.in/content/www/in/en/architecture-and-technology/widi-pro-widi-discontinued-notice.html

Answer (score 6):

```
cmd> netsh wlan show driver
Wireless Display Supported: No (Graphics Driver: No, Wi-Fi Driver: No)
```

or `dxdiag` and "Save details" where::

```
System Information
  Miracast: Not Available
```